# How to prevent location caching in android?

Tags: android, caching, geolocation

Android location caching saves some power. But given that recently cached GPS location can be sent to Google server for Network location provider purpose, there is some privacy concern there. How can I prevent the location fix caching or prevent Android Network location provider from accessing the most recent location?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about privacy concerns with Android.  There is a StackExchange group for Android Enthusiasts I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have no control of this within an app. The location stack is built in as part of the operating system and location sharing provides great value to google. You are incorrect that just 'cached' location information is shared with google.

From `Settings > Location access` a user can manually disable cellular/wifi location sharing. Android shares location data here for the purpose of mapping wifi locations and cellular towers. If a user opts-out of this, they are not able to receive "coarse" location updates.

Outside of this, Google applications themselves also share location data. This needs to be disabled from the Google Settings menu. See [this help page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3118687).

In brief, if your user wishes to not share location access, they will need to manually go through the steps of opting-out and then accept a degraded experience. Custom ROMs or applications that have root access may also have a solution for some users.